# “We can't save the customer” getting this error while creating new customer on Magento 2

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.2

I am getting error when new user comes on register page after filling all data when click on submit button got this error **"We cant save customer"**. when i check my system.log
it shows me this type of error.

**Exception message:
 Class Lotus\Override\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupId does not exist**
Trace:

```
 **Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Lotus\Override\O...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]**
```

I dont know where this error comes because there is no Lotus_Observer module in my magento 2.3.2

Can anyone have an idea how to solve this error ?

Comment: Can you please check in your **app/etc/config.php** file and there is any modules available like **Lotus_Override** ?

Comment: yes i hvae already checked there i no module related to Lotus

Comment: which Magento version you are using ?

Comment: magento 2.3.2 which  I have already mentioned

Comment: can you please remove generated directory using rm -rf generated and then run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command and check ?

Comment: let me try ..this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99903/discussion-between-hemangi-patel-and-kishan-savaliya).